# Play! 2.0 with Scala and AJAX tutorial/example

Tags: ajax, jquery, playframework, playframework-2.0

I am looking for a clean vanilla example of the play framework with ajax. I would like to build a a dependent dropdown and a chained select. All the tutorials on the web I have found uses php.

The only sample that has ajax makes use of coffee script.

Is there one out there somewhere?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't really need a Scala tutorial for that, you can follow the PHP ones.
The difference is that your data (responses) will be returned by Scala routes instead of PHP scripts.

To learn more about AJAX calls in Play just examine a `zentasks` sample delivered to you together with Play's code. There are samples for both Scala and Java versions and all you have to test them is to go to the folder of selected sample via commandline and run/start it as a common Play's application.

[Preview](http://www.playframework.org/documentation/2.0/Samples)

Comment: Thanks to you both, I will use that inconjunction with this post I found. http://www.objectify.be/wordpress/?p=428